# Understanding lexical scoping - is Wikipedia correct?

Tags: bash, scope, lexical-scope

I've been trying to grok lexical scoping (I'm far from convinced by the use of the word *lexical* but that's another discussion) and I've looked at [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping).

According to the fairly simple Bash script example

```
$ x=1 
$ function g () { echo $x ; x=2 ; }
$ function f () { local x=3 ; g ; }
$ f # does this print 1, or 3?
3
$ echo $x # does this print 1, or 2?
1
```

the output from the Bash script is 3, 1.  However, it seems to me that it ought to be 3, 2 because the function g prints the (dynamic) value of x and then sets the value of x = 2.

Do I need to correct the Wikipedia entry, or adjust my understanding?

Comment: It set the local var in f to 2, when f ends, the var is binned. Put `echo $x` after `g;`

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies things for me.

Answer (score 3):

Bash vars use the [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) just as in the wiki page you mentioned.

> Examples of languages that use dynamic scoping include Logo, Emacs Lisp, and the shell languages **bash**, dash, and PowerShell.
>
> Dynamic scoping is fairly easy to implement. *To find an identifier's value, the program could traverse the runtime stack, checking each activation record (each function's stack frame) for a value for the identifier.*

Bash's own [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says this:

> The shell uses **dynamic scoping** to control a variable's visibility
> within  functions.   With  dynamic scoping,  visible  variables  and
> their  values  are a result of the sequence of function calls that
> caused execution to reach the current function.  The value of a
> variable that a function sees depends on  its  value  within its
> caller, if any, whether that caller is the "global" scope or another
> shell function.  This is also the value that a local variable
> declaration "shadows", and the value that  is restored when the
> function returns.
>
> For  example, if a variable `var` is declared as local in function
> `func1`, and `func1` calls another function `func2`, references to `var` made
> from within `func2` will resolve to  the  local  variable  `var`  from
> `func1`, shadowing any global variable named `var`.

For how this can be used see [Bash: Passing variables by reference](http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference).

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash` man page description of the `local` built-in (emphasis mine)

> When local is used within a function, it causes the
>                 variable name to have a visible scope restricted to  that  function  **and  its children**.

When `g` is called, the value of `x` (not being marked `local`) is used from the closest enclosing *runtime* context. When `g` is called from `f`, that means the local variable `x` defined by `f`, not the global variable `x`. This applies both to the lookup *and* assignments to `x`. When `g` is called from the global scope, `x` refers to the global variable `x`.

This contrasts with lexical scoping, in which the `x` in the function `g` would always refer to global `x`, because `g` is *defined* in the global scope. Where a function is called *from* isn't relevant.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I hope it's ok to ask. :) I'm sitting in front of a shell program which hardly uses dynamic scoping, mainly to pass arrays between functions. Variables are used in different functions and combination of functions and those functions are spread across five source files. In my opinion this code is less readable/followable and the fact that functions are tightly coupled makes it prone to bugs and hard to maintain. Would you say that this is just normal practice for shell code and I have to expect that or do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

`g` assigns 2 to the local `x` of the function `f`. When `f` ends, his activation record is popped from the stack, then the second echo looks up in the stack and finds the `x = 1` of the beginning.