# how bash one line variable affect variable scope

Tags: bash, variables

```
x=1

function f()
{
    echo $x
}

x=2 f #2

function g()
{
    x=3
    a=4
    echo $x
}
a=5
x=2 g  #3
echo $x  #1
echo $a  #4
```

Why the output is
2
3
1
4
?
Why function f access the one line variable x rather than the global one? Why function g create global variables x and a, but the x does not override outside global one?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165818/understanding-lexical-scoping-is-wikipedia-correct and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998075/setting-environment-variable-for-one-program-call-in-bash-using-env

Comment: While we are on the topic, do also check the [`local`](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html) keyword.

Comment: `function h()
{
    local x=3;
    echo $x; 
}

x=2 h` This output is 3.So I can say the order is LEG: local -> environ -> global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why function f access the one line variable x rather than the global one?

Because specifying a variable as part of a command sets it in the dynamic scope of the execution of that command (only).

> Why function g create global variables x and a, but the x does not override outside global one?

`g` assigns to variables `x` and `a`. But *in the context of the call* `x` is effectively local to it, on account of a value having been specified for that variable as part of the call.  The same is not true of `a`, so the assignment to it affects the shell environment normally.

Comment: Well, I got it. Function g does not overide global x but assign for the outside one line variable x.